# Rails Froala editor 500 error on production

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rubygems, froala

What can it be? On dev mode i have no problems. But on production editor doesn't work and i have 500 errors on editor css files
My application.css.scss:

```
@import "froala_editor.min.css";
@import "froala_style.min.css";
@import "font-awesome-sprockets";
@import "font-awesome";
@import 'plugins/char_counter.min.css';
@import 'plugins/code_view.min.css';
@import 'plugins/colors.min.css';
@import 'plugins/emoticons.min.css';
@import 'plugins/file.min.css';
@import 'plugins/fullscreen.min.css';
@import 'plugins/help.min.css';
@import 'plugins/image_manager.min.css';
@import 'plugins/image.min.css';
@import 'plugins/line_breaker.min.css';
@import 'plugins/quick_insert.min.css';
@import 'plugins/special_characters.min.css';
@import 'plugins/table.min.css';
@import 'plugins/video.min.css';
```

[image: logs]

Comment: Can you post your server logs?

Comment: sure, it's seems taht my app want to include file without pepline
`I, [2017-04-23T13:41:11.988065 #30538]  INFO -- : Started GET "/assets/froala_style.min.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-04-23 13:41:11 +0200
F, [2017-04-23T13:41:11.988794 #30538] FATAL -- :   
F, [2017-04-23T13:41:11.988838 #30538] FATAL -- : ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/assets/froala_style.min.css"):
F, [2017-04-23T13:41:11.988861 #30538] FATAL -- :   
F, [2017-04-23T13:41:11.988883 #30538] FATAL -- : actionpack (5.0.2) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:53:in `call'`

Comment: on mypublic/assets folder i have files but with pepline

Comment: Yes, it seems so, where are you running on production? Have you precompiled your assets (`rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production`)?

Comment: yes, i've done it rake assets:precompile RAILS_ENV=production

Comment: if i set config.assets.compile = true - it's work fine